# How can I destroy Authority Sentries in Rage 2?

Tags: rage-2

There's an Authority Sentry pretty centralized between Vineland and Gunbarrel that has a threat ranking of 2, I assumed this would be fairly easy to destroy, but I can't seem to be dealing any damage to it!

The sentry is tightly surrounded by buildings so vehicular combat isn't feasible. I've already tried deploying mini-nukes using the common Rolla vehicle, but the tight alleyways meant I'd get blasted before being able to deploy. Similarly, trying to shoot the top of the sentry using the chainguns from the Pheonix while using the buildings for cover dealt no damage to the structure.

Battling on foot was equally difficult as my early-game combat shotgun, assault rifle and grenades were ineffective.

Do Authority Sentries have a weak point I should target specifically or do I need to return with better weapons and upgrades? Is there any other way to demolish these laser towers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get close enough until it "deploys," then shoot the blue part near the center.

Each time the sentry "charges up," take cover behind something or else you'll be hit almost immediately and take tons of damage.  It will also occasionally send out electric shockwaves that you must jump over (or duck under).

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't getting close enough to see the big glowing weak point on the towers. I kept taking cover behind objects that obstructed my view of the sentry. I've since destroyed a few. It's worth noting that some of the sentries have other attacks like an orbital bombardment and homing missiles.